# Is there a way to keep on looping a switch statement if a user enters anything other than an integer in c++?

Tags: c++

My loop works for a scenario where a user enters a number not in the list but when I insert a character or string, the loop does'nt work. I wanted to make it such that it'll keep on looping as long as the switch statement case is default, irregardles of whether its a number or character.
I tried choice!=int and choice==string to create a while loop but apparently its not possible.

```
void userDetails();
int main()
{
    userDetails();
    return 0;
}
void userDetails()
{
    cout << "Select a username below:" << endl;
    cout << "1. " << firstname + lastname << flush << endl;
    cout << "2. " << lastname + firstname << flush << endl;
    cout << "3. " << firstname + "254" << flush << endl;
    cout << "4. " << lastname + "254" << flush << endl;
    cout << "5. Enter other username:" << flush << endl;
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        username = firstname + lastname;
        cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        username = lastname + firstname;
        cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        username = firstname + "254";
        cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        username = lastname + "254";
        cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Create a username:" << endl;
        cin >> username;
        cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid option, please try again!!!!";
        break;
    }
    while (choice > 5)
    {
        cout << "Select a username below:" << endl;
        cout << "1. " << firstname + lastname << flush << endl;
        cout << "2. " << lastname + firstname << flush << endl;
        cout << "3. " << firstname + "254" << flush << endl;
        cout << "4. " << lastname + "254" << flush << endl;
        cout << "5. Enter other username:" << flush << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            username = firstname + lastname;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            username = lastname + firstname;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            username = firstname + "254";
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            username = lastname + "254";
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Create a username:" << endl;
            cin >> username;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option, please try again!!!!";
            break;
        }
    }
    while (choice ==0)
    {
        cout << "Select a username below:" << endl;
        cout << "1. " << firstname + lastname << flush << endl;
        cout << "2. " << lastname + firstname << flush << endl;
        cout << "3. " << firstname + "254" << flush << endl;
        cout << "4. " << lastname + "254" << flush << endl;
        cout << "5. Enter other username:" << flush << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            username = firstname + lastname;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            username = lastname + firstname;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            username = firstname + "254";
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            username = lastname + "254";
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Create a username:" << endl;
            cin >> username;
            cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username" << flush << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option, please try again!!!!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::cin.fail`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) or [`std::cin.operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (which is the inverse of `fail`) to determine whether the input conversion was successful.

Also, your code has a lot of unnecessary code duplication, which will probably also not work. What you need is an infinite loop which you will only break out of as soon as the input has been determined to be valid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cctype>

void userDetails();

int main()
{
    userDetails();
    return 0;
}

void userDetails()
{
    std::string firstname{ "John" };
    std::string lastname{ "Doe" };
    std::string username;

    while ( true ) //infinite loop
    {
        char c;
        bool has_invalid_characters = false;

        std::cout <<
            "Select a username below:\n" << 
            "1. " << firstname + lastname << '\n' <<
            "2. " << lastname + firstname << '\n' <<
            "3. " << firstname + "254" << '\n' <<
            "4. " << lastname + "254" << '\n' <<
            "5. Enter other username\n" <<
            "\n" <<
            "Please select an option: ";

        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;

        if ( !std::cin ) //this uses std::cin.operator bool
        {
            std::cout << "Input must be a number!\n\n";

            //clear failure flag
            std::cin.clear();

            //discard remainder of line from input stream
            std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //check whether remainder of line consists only of
        //whitespace characters
        while ( std::cin.get( c ) && c != '\n' )
        {
            if ( !std::isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>(c) ) )
            {
                has_invalid_characters = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( has_invalid_characters )
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid character found after number!\n\n";

            //discard remainder of line from input stream
            std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        switch ( choice )
        {
        case 1:
            username = firstname + lastname;
            std::cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username.\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            username = lastname + firstname;
            std::cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username.\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            username = firstname + "254";
            std::cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username.\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            username = lastname + "254";
            std::cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username.\n";
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "Create a username:\n";
            std::cin >> username;
            std::cout << "You have selected " << username << " as your username.\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid option, please try again!\n\n";
            continue;
        }

        //input was valid, so break out of infinite loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Select a username below:
1. JohnDoe
2. DoeJohn
3. John254
4. Doe254
5. Enter other username

Please select an option: ThisIsAString
Input must be a number!

Select a username below:
1. JohnDoe
2. DoeJohn
3. John254
4. Doe254
5. Enter other username

Please select an option: 34
Invalid option, please try again!

Select a username below:
1. JohnDoe
2. DoeJohn
3. John254
4. Doe254
5. Enter other username

Please select an option: 2abc
Invalid character found after number!

Select a username below:
1. JohnDoe
2. DoeJohn
3. John254
4. Doe254
5. Enter other username

Please select an option: 2
You have selected DoeJohn as your username.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do as below.

1. read a string instead of integer.
2. parse string to integer.
3. if there are parsing error or less than 1 or greater than 5, run while loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring an `int` and using it as a number, you can declare a character and only use it as a number when it actually is a number, something like (pseudo-code):

```
char str_choice;
cin >> str_choice;
if ((str_choice <= '9') && (str_choice >= 0))
{
  int choice = (int)str_choice - (int)'0'; // this part you might need to rework
  switch (choice)
  ...
} else
  cout << "You have not entered an integer, so you have lost the game" << endl;
```

Comment: This solution has the problem that in the second loop iteration, the newline character will be stored in `str_choice`. Also, the input should be rejected if the user enters more than one character, which your code is not doing.